# Not able to save rendered PDF in chrome - Perl

Tags: php, perl, internet-explorer, google-chrome, pdf

I have HTML web form. If user fill the form, the form details generated as PDF in the next tab. There is no problem with the PDF generation. It's displaying in browser properly. When i try to save the pdf in Chrome.  it's not working.

**Content Details**
        Content_type : application/pdf;
        Content-Disposition : inline;filename=test.pdf;

Also i have another issue in IE & Safari. The file name is different when i save the PDF in IE & Safari. (not **test.pdf**)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens in Chrome?

Comment: I could't save the PDF in Chrome. The Save button is not working. I am using chrome default pdf viewer.

Comment: So you are seeing the PDF-File in chromes PDFViewer? And the save button in the lower right corner can not be activated? or does nothing happen when you click onto the save-button? On what Operating-System are you running chrome? Does the same issue arrise in a different operating system? Does a "right-click onto the PDF" give you the oportunity to "Save as"? what happens when you simply hit Ctrl-S (Cmd-S on Mac)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes the lower right cornet button is not working. Also when i tried  to save the pdf using CTRL + S & right click "Save AS". it's not working. I Am using Win 7 - Chrome. I did't check it in Mac Machine. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224520 on the internet. So when your PDF file is retrieved with a POST-request the plugin seems to be unable to retrieve the same resource for the download. So I'd test whether delivering the file with a GET-request solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check.

Comment: So, using a GET does circumnavigate the issue - but it introduces another issue - GET requests have limited length.  Is there another way to work around?

Comment: You could use POST to create the PDF and store it on the server and then redirect to a GET to fetch that stored file. That way you'll use GET for retrieval but can send any length of parameters. You'll need to implement something to get rid of that file after some time though....

Answer (score 0):

Add the filename as last part to the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/download/pdf/test.pdf?param1=val1&
```

That schould work in IE